# Django Query Filter using Try: Except:

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter users who:

1. fit my preference
2. whose preference fits me
3. randomly
4. on the chat page in the last 5 seconds and
5. exclude myself

The problem is that sometimes there are no users who were on in the last 5 seconds. In this case, I want to take that out of the query because it would put my list index out of range and throw an error.

So I defined my exception clause first and then hopefully it would get rewritten if the try: block does not throw an indexError. This doesn't happen, it still throws the error. How do I avoid the error?

```
recent_range = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=5)
all_users = User.objects.filter(gender=user_preference).\
    filter(preference=user_gender).order_by('?').exclude(email=request.user.email)
try:
    all_users = User.objects.filter(gender=user_preference).\
        filter(preference=user_gender).filter(online=recent_range).\
        order_by('?').exclude(email=request.user.email)
except IndexError:
    pass
other_user = all_users[0]
```

Comment: There's nothing in either query that would throw an IndexError. It must be coming from somewhere else; please provide the full traceback.

Comment: You're right! this didnt give me the indexError. all_users[0] gave me the error. If I put the all_users[0] inside the block, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Roseman helped me figure this out. The filters were not throwing the error. Calling an index on an empty query was. If you put other_user[0] inside the block, it won't throw the error

```
all_users = User.objects.filter(gender=user_preference).\
    filter(preference=user_gender).order_by('?').exclude(email=request.user.email)
other_user = all_users[0]
try:
    all_users = User.objects.filter(gender=user_preference).\
        filter(preference=user_gender).filter(online=recent_range).\
        order_by('?').exclude(email=request.user.email)
    other_user = all_users[0]
except:
    pass
```